# Select all records that are not yet in the record set

Tags: sql-server-2008

The database I am working with currently does have two tables, one holding the attribute "contact_person". This attribute is compared to several attributes (*not tuples!*) in another table which are named "contact1" to "contact4" to determine what other attributes to display from the second table (i.e. "email1" to "email4"). So the first table only holds the contact person, the second the actual address data for several contact persons (again, all of them in a row or a single tuple). Do not tell me that this aint proper database design - I have to work with what I was given -.-

To get the proper contact data I chose to perform a select for each comparison and UNION them. This works fine and executes well enough for the application that performs the query. It looks, very simplified, something like this:

```
SELECT contact1, email1, phone1 FROM T1,T2 WHERE contact_person = contact1
UNION ALL
SELECT contact2, email2, phone2 FROM T1,T2 WHERE contact_person = contact2
UNION ALL
SELECT contact3, email3, phone3 FROM T1,T2 WHERE contact_person = contact3
UNION ALL
SELECT contact4, email4, phone4 FROM T1,T2 WHERE contact_person = contact4
```

Now, due to malformed and non-error-checked INSERT queries, it is possible that "contact_person" is NULL or an empty string or that any of the "contactN" attributes is NULL. So I need another SELECT query that displays *all records that are in the database but are not in the record-set yet*.

With the given example that could be achieved using something similar to this:

```
UNION
SELECT contact_person, 'N/A', 'N/A' FROM T1,T2
```

In the real life query I (need to) do a lot of formatting of "contact_person" and the "contactN"s, so simply doing a UNION (without the ALL, so equal records get excluded) wont work (contactN is actually a multi field value and the formatting is not consistent, so the records returned by the last query might differ from the records above, even for the same entry in the database). Also, the query is so enormous already that it is no option to use the opposite of the first query to exclude its records, like so:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT contact_person, 'N/A', 'N/A' FROM T1,T2
    WHERE contact_person <> contact1
    AND contact_person <> contact2
    AND contact_person <> contact3
    AND contact_person <> contact4
```

So is there another way to display all records that have not been selected with the very first query posted above? Maybe by somehow running a subquery (ofc there does exists a UID for the returned records - I just dont know how to work with it in this context)? Could the very first query have been written in a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cp AS
(
    -- strongly recommend appropriate table prefixes in select list:
    SELECT UID, contact1, email1, phone1 
    -- also strongly recommend proper inner joins:
        FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.contact_person = t2.contact1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UID, contact2, email2, phone2 
        FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.contact_person = t2.contact2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UID, contact3, email3, phone3
        FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.contact_person = t2.contact3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UID, contact4, email4, phone4 
        FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.contact_person = t2.contact4
)
SELECT contact1, email1, phone1 FROM cp
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.contact_person, 'N/A', 'N/A'
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.contact_person = t2.contact1
WHERE UID NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM cp);
```

You might also consider a more normalized/relational design?

Comment: Oh, I am working with table prefixes and joins - I only tried to keep it short and simple. Also I unfortunately do not have the option of redesigning any part of the database for now. This will only happen when the application that accesses it will be rewritten which is when the company I currently work for finds it has the necessary monetary resources to do so. And I am trying to convince them for quite a while now. Anyway, this looks a lot like what I need - only that I cannot test it today (its closing time in our company). I will check it and mark the answer tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could first normalise `T2`, then left join it:

```
WITH normalisedT2 AS (
  SELECT
    contact = CASE x.n
      WHEN 1 THEN T2.contact1
      WHEN 2 THEN T2.contact2
      WHEN 3 THEN T2.contact3
      WHEN 4 THEN T2.contact4
    END,
    email = CASE x.n
      WHEN 1 THEN T2.email1
      WHEN 2 THEN T2.email2
      WHEN 3 THEN T2.email3
      WHEN 4 THEN T2.email4
    END,
    phone = CASE x.n
      WHEN 1 THEN T2.phone1
      WHEN 2 THEN T2.phone2
      WHEN 3 THEN T2.phone3
      WHEN 4 THEN T2.phone4
    END
  FROM T2
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4
    ) x (n)
)
SELECT
  contact = T1.contact_person,
  email   = COALESCE(T2.email, 'N/A'),
  phone   = COALESCE(T2.phone, 'N/A')
FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN normalisedT2 T2 ON T1.contact_person = T2.contact
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I already implemented Aarons version, but its great to see it solved another way also. I didn't have time yet to compare both versions performance-wise (only implemented your version on a small test-db), which I'll do just out of interest and to learn a little bit more. So thanks and +1